# How to monitor disk I/O in Linux without iotop?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bash, bandwidth

I recently discovered iotop, which is Python program that monitors disk I/O in real time. It shows me which program is reading and writing the most and the rate.

Iotop is problematic however. Getting it to start when the drive is being hammed takes a while, perhaps a minute or three.

Is there a more direct way to monitor disk I/O? If I use BASH, can I find the same info in /proc?

Answer (score 2):

`htop` will do this and is pretty lightweight, you'll just have to [add the IO columns to the display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350302/247007).

That linked answer also has plenty of other good alternatives, though focused on permissions rather than overhead.

Comment: But where is htop getting its disk I/O metrics? Is it making some ioctl calls or is it maybe reading from /proc?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse `/proc` yourself, you should be able to get most information from `/proc/[pid]/io`. See `man 5 proc` for what these figures mean. You would need to keep a count of the parameters, because they are just totals up to the moment that you read them.